# Did some early jet engines catch on fire at higher power settings?

Tags: jet-engine

Recently I've being playing some [IL-2 1946](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IL-2_Sturmovik:_1946), and in this flight simulator jet engines had a strange problem where if I suddenly throttle up more than 60% the engines would catch on fire. Is this a real thing? The engines that this happens on are the Jumo 004 and the BMW 003 on the Me 262 and the He 162.

Answer (score 8):

Yes indeed. For the [Jumo 004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Jumo_004):

> [A] shortcoming of the engine, common to all early turbojets, was its sluggish throttle response. Worse, it was fairly easy to inject too much fuel into the engine by **throttling up too quickly,** allowing heat to build up before the cooling air could remove it. This led to softening of the turbine blades, and was a major cause for engine failures.

To avoid rapid movements the levers of that era (and still being used on some types) had a friction setting that can be increased on decreased. High friction results in more force required to move the thrust lever.

Advancements in the hydromechanical units and the introduction of [engine control units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FADEC) made controlling a jet engine much easier.

I remember reading (but I can't seem to find it now) that [Frank Whittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Whittle) had problems shutting down one of the early jet engines he worked on. It would just keep running and speeding up.

Comment: The materials shortages that prevented production J004s from using the high-temperature alloys the engine was designed to use surely didn't help in that regard...